# Send an HTML email using the Gmail API

Tags: javascript, gmail-api

For some reason the Gmail API won't send an html email. Sending plaintext works fine:

```
var message = 'From: Me <me@gmail.com>\r\n' +
    'To: Me <me@gmail.com>\r\n' +
    'Subject: Hello\r\n\r\n'
    'World'

var raw = btoa(message)
```

Then when I try html, it just shows up as an empty message:

```
var message = 'From: Me <me@gmail.com>\r\n' +
    'To: Me <me@gmail.com>\r\n' +
    'Subject: Hello\r\n'
    'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n' +
    'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\r\n\r\n' +
    '<html><body>' +
    '<h1>World</h1>' +
    '</body></html>'

var raw = btoa(message)
```

Any ideas? Maybe because it's not RFC 2822 compliant?

Comment: How do you send mails using JavaScript?

Comment: I'm using javascript to send a post request to the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send) where the raw variable is the parameter in the request. Sorry, I realize I didn't really provide any context in the question.

Comment: How are you creating rfc2822 string, message variable in the above example. I sit hard coded or Is there any other ways to that? @rob

Comment: @robs, Are inline styles working for your?

Comment: Can I please see your full code?  I have this exact same problem right now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters you need to use base64url encoding, using the web/url safe alphabet not just the standard btoa() base64.  If that doesn't fix it can you post your code and the exact error message you're getting?  (Or does it work and not show up as html?)

Comment: Hm I tried 'encodeURI(btoa(message))' but I get a 400 when there's a '+' character, so I think it is supposed be standard base64. Sending the html email actual goes through error free, it's just that the resulting message body is empty.

Comment: it's not encodeURI() that's not it either. you want base64url() which is like btoa() but it doesn't use "/" and "+". btoa() may work fine if nothing happens to get encoded to "/" or "+".  :) if there's no base64url in javascript just btoa() then .replace("/", "_").replace("+", "-").

can you include entire response (both HTTP headers + body)?  there should definitely be a body.

Comment: Right on, btoa(message).replace('/', '_').replace('+', '-') works perfect. Thank you sir!

Comment: Oops, not quite perfect, gotta remember to apply it globally: `btoa(message).replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/\+/g, '-')`

Comment: if you are sending email with chinese in body, this is correct way: btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(mail))).replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/\+/g, '-'); For chinese subject: "=?UTF-8?B?" + btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(subject))) + "?="

Comment: @EricDeFriez, My inline style is not working? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271938/gmail-api-html-inline-styles-are-not-applying