# gmail api html inline styles are not applying

Tags: node.js, post, meteor, google-api, gmail-api

I'm using gmail api and I'm trying to send the following code as mail

For ex:

I'm sending this

```
<tr>
     <td style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:9px;">
       <a>Buy what you wish &amp; Get Flat 5% off Use: HOLIDAY5</a>
     </td>
    </tr>
```

and in the mail I'm receiving this

```
    <tr>
     <td>
       <a>Buy what you wish &amp; Get Flat 5% off Use: HOLIDAY5</a>
     </td>
    </tr>
```

all my inline styles are gone

my post request is

```
        var from= 'From: '+name+' <'+email+'>\r\n';
        var to='To: Me '+' <'+to+'>\r\n';
        var subject= 'Subject: '+subj+'\r\n';
        var mail='<html><body>'+sHTML+'</body></html>';
        var message = from + to +  subject +
        'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n' +
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\r\n\r\n' +
        mail;

        var ss=new Buffer(message).toString('base64');
        var rawdata = ss.replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/\+/g, '-');
```

**//Sending POST request**

```
var headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + google.accessToken}
var options={contentType: "application/json"};
var res = HTTP.post('https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send',{params: options,headers: headers,data: {'raw':rawdata}});
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question to give a smaller, properly indented example? This example is both poorly indented and wrong (`font-siz=...`). [More here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you include the code where the variable `sHTML` is set?

Comment: Try specifying the content-type header  to "application/json".

Comment: Does the Gmail web compose interface somehow allow this?  (Or are you just comparing expectations of the REST API against SMTP (MSA)?)

Comment: @SGC, If i give "application/json" it is sending as attachement with message

Comment: @BrianShamblen, sHTML is a `summernote` output, it is a text editor, the code that I gave in my original question is the value I'm passing to sHTML

Comment: @EricDeFriez, REST API doesn't support inline styling? I haven't seen anybody doing that, no mention in the docs too. So, I'm trying. You're from gmail api team, can you confirm that rest api doesn't support sending inline styles.