# Send HTML email with plain text fallback via Gmail API

Tags: java, email, gmail, gmail-api

[An answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26769952/send-an-html-email-using-the-gmail-api) at StackOverflow suggests that adding html-markup to the body of the email will do the trick. Is that solution correct?

But what if the recipient's email server/client does not support HTML email?

E.g. when using [Apache commons email](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/userguide.html), I do the following:

```
// set the html message
email.setHtmlMsg("<html>Our logo - <img src=\"cid:"+cid+"\"></html>");
// set the alternative message
email.setTextMsg("Your email client does not support HTML messages");
```

Is there any way to tell Gmail API what email to fall back to if the recipient email server/client does not support HTML?

P.S.
I'm especially interested in Java code samples.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To give two alternatives, you can set the `Content-Type` to `mixed/alternative` instead of either `text/plain` or `text/html`:

If we want to try this out in the [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send), we just Base64-encode the mail, and make it url-safe by replacing all `/` with `_` and all `+` with `-`.

In the Developer Console:

```
btoa(
  "Subject: Example Subject\r\n" +
  "From: <example@gmail.com>\r\n" +
  "To: <example@gmail.com>\r\n" +
  "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"foo_bar\"\r\n\r\n" +

  "--foo_bar\r\n" +
  "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n" +

  "*Bold example message text*\r\n\r\n" +

  "--foo_bar\r\n" +
  "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n" +

  "<div dir=\"ltr\"><b>Bold example message text</b></div>\r\n\r\n" +

  "--foo_bar--" 
).replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_');

POST https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send?access_token={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
 "raw": "U3ViamVjdDogRXhhbXBsZSBTdWJqZWN0DQpGcm9tOiA8ZXhhbXBsZUBnbWFpbC5jb20-DQpUbzogPGV4YW1wbGVAZ21haWwuY29tPg0KQ29udGVudC1UeXBlOiBtdWx0aXBhcnQvYWx0ZXJuYXRpdmU7IGJvdW5kYXJ5PSJmb29fYmFyIg0KDQotLWZvb19iYXINCkNvbnRlbnQtVHlwZTogdGV4dC9wbGFpbjsgY2hhcnNldD1VVEYtOA0KDQoqQm9sZCBleGFtcGxlIG1lc3NhZ2UgdGV4dCoNCg0KLS1mb29fYmFyDQpDb250ZW50LVR5cGU6IHRleHQvaHRtbDsgY2hhcnNldD1VVEYtOA0KDQo8ZGl2IGRpcj0ibHRyIj48Yj5Cb2xkIGV4YW1wbGUgbWVzc2FnZSB0ZXh0PC9iPjwvZGl2Pg0KDQotLWZvb19iYXItLQ=="
}
```

To do the equivalent in Java, you could do:

```
Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
Multipart multiPart = new MimeMultipart("alternative");

MimeBodyPart textPart = new MimeBodyPart();
textPart.setText(text, "utf-8");

MimeBodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
htmlPart.setContent(html, "text/html; charset=utf-8");

multiPart.addBodyPart(textPart); 
multiPart.addBodyPart(htmlPart);
message.setContent(multiPart);

ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
message.writeTo(output);
String rawEmail = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(output.toByteArray());

Message message = new Message();
message.setRaw(rawEmail);
message = service.users().messages().send(userId, message).execute();
```

Comment: Thanks you! Looks like exactly the right thing to do. Testing it.

Comment: @LevRatinov Sweet! :) Glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

To add an update to above answer from **Throlle**.
There were some differences in above and possibly with the later versions of gmail api

to send a message and follow their default provided standards for sending a standard email :

This is in grails but you can easily change for java, the controller stuff pre this html stuff can be [found here](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/gmail-api-test). Maybe when I am finished with what I am doing and get a chance will update the github site with all these examples:

In controller [sendHTMLEmail](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/gmail-api-test/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/test/TestingController.groovy#L107-L116):

```
  def sendHTMLEmail() {
        String emailBox='me@gmail.com'
        String to ='someuser@domain.com'
        String html="<html><body><table><tr><td><b>aa</b></td><td>bb</td></tr></table><h1>html content</h1></body></html>"
        MimeMessage content = gmailService.createHTMLEmail(to,emailBox,'gmail test','testing gmail via app',html)
        def message = gmailService.sendMessage(gmail,'me',content)
        render "=== ${message.id}"
}
```

In Service [createHTMLEmail](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/gmail-api-test/blob/master/grails-app/services/gmail/GmailService.groovy#L204-L225)

```
public static MimeMessage createHTMLEmail(String to, String from, String subject, String text, String html) {
        Properties props = new Properties()
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null)

        MimeMessage email = new MimeMessage(session)
        Multipart multiPart = new MimeMultipart("alternative")
        email.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from))
        email.addRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to))
        email.setSubject(subject)

        MimeBodyPart textPart = new MimeBodyPart()
        textPart.setText(text, "utf-8")

        MimeBodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart()
        htmlPart.setContent(html, "text/html; charset=utf-8")
        
        multiPart.addBodyPart(textPart)
        multiPart.addBodyPart(htmlPart)
        email.setContent(multiPart)
        return email
    }
```

Then their standard provided [sendMessage](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/gmail-api-test/blob/master/grails-app/services/gmail/GmailService.groovy#L165-L193) (below bits can be found on github link):

```
public static Message sendMessage(Gmail service,String userId,MimeMessage emailContent) throws MessagingException, IOException {
        try {
            Message message = createMessageWithEmail(emailContent)
            message = service.users().messages().send(userId, message).execute()
            return message
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //log.error "${e}"
        }
    }
```

and createMessageWithEmail

```
public static Message createMessageWithEmail(MimeMessage emailContent) throws MessagingException, IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
        emailContent.writeTo(buffer)
        byte[] bytes = buffer.toByteArray()
        String encodedEmail = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(bytes)
        Message message = new Message()
        message.setRaw(encodedEmail)
        return message
    }
```

Comment: as a side note, unsure if peeps from google keep an eye out on this list. If so maybe worth adding this example to your existing examples your api doc site. Since although it was a quite a minor process for me to figure out how to all do this properly. I suspect to a novice beginner this may be overwhelmingly too complex to figure such things out

Comment: Absolutely Correct. Sigh!