# How to set authorization for sending mail through Gmail Api in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, gmail-api, login-required

I am trying to send mail using Gmail Api in javascript but i am getting 401 error (Login Required). My application is already authorized, I have an access token.

This is my piece of code that i am trying to run:

```
 gapi.client.load('gmail', 'v1', 
 var email = ''{my mail content};

var sendRequest = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.send({
'userId': 'me',
'resource': {
  'raw': window.btoa(email).replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_')
}

});
return sendRequest.execute(callback);
});
```

Please help me what to do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read their API docs?

Comment: Yes i have read. But i am not able to find a suitable solution how to send the access token with my call to authorize the Gmail API call.

Comment: Are you doing this on the back-end with Nodejs, or on the front-end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you are sending the message from the front end, you don't really need to use the client library. You could just use JQuery or something similar:

```
// You can test with your own account by getting a token here:
// https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/
var accessToken = 'ya29...';
// Base64-encode the mail and make it URL-safe
// (replace all '+' with '-' and all '/' with '_')
var encodedMail = btoa([
  'From: sender@gmail.com\r\n',
  'To: receiver@gmail.com\r\n',
  'Subject: Subject Text\r\n\r\n',

  'Message Text'
].join('')).replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_');

$.ajax({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  data: JSON.stringify({
    'raw': encodedMail
  })
});
```

You can just encode a mail and try it in the [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send#try-it) first.

Comment: it is f9 with plain text what if i want to send HTML code within email ,so that it will come up with better ui.

Comment: @ShubhamNigam You can check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34165219/send-html-email-with-plain-text-fallback-via-gmail-api) to see how you can give a plain text and a html text alternative. If you are using Browserify, you can use a [tiny dependency-free module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gmail-api-create-message-body) I wrote a while back, or your can read the code to get some inspiration.